# I am trying this command. "make stm32f429-discovery"

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-12.04, stm32f4discovery

I am trying this command. `make stm32f429-discovery` 
I have stm32f429-discovery board (arm cortex M3). and i want to install **u-boot** on it,i am trying this as per given in tutorial, and get this error.......

```
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
Configuring for stm32f429-discovery board...
make
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot'
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
Generating include/autoconf.mk
/bin/bash: line 3: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
Generating include/autoconf.mk.dep
/bin/bash: line 3: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot'
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot'
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
for dir in tools examples/standalone examples/api cpu/arm_cortexm3 /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3/ ; do \
            make -C $dir _depend ; done
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/tools'
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/standalone'
/bin/sh: 1: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/standalone'
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/api'
/bin/sh: 1: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/api'
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3'
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3'
make -C tools all
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/tools'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/tools'
make -C examples/standalone all
/bin/bash: /home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/standalone'
/bin/sh: 1: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc  -g  -Os   -g2 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -fsigned-char -O2 -fno-builtin-puts -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -D__KERNEL__ -I/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -isystem  -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__ -DCONFIG_MEM_NVM_BASE= -DCONFIG_MEM_NVM_LEN= -DCONFIG_MEM_NVM_UBOOT_OFF=0x0 -DCONFIG_MEM_RAM_BASE= -DCONFIG_MEM_RAM_LEN= -DCONFIG_MEM_RAM_BUF_LEN= -DCONFIG_MEM_MALLOC_LEN= -DCONFIG_MEM_STACK_LEN= -I/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/cpu/arm_cortexm3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -o hello_world.o hello_world.c -c
make[2]: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
make[2]: *** [hello_world.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot/examples/standalone'
make[1]: *** [examples/standalone] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/uzair/Documents/linux-cortexm-1.12.1/u-boot'
make: *** [stm32f429-discovery] Error 2
```

Comment: Your build toolchain is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

STM32F429 Discovery is based on ARM Cortex-M4F instead of Cortex-M3 core. You might consider to use another builder to prepare u-boot + uClinux + root file system images: https://github.com/jserv/stm32f429-linux-builder

Answer (score 0):

You must set to correct path

For example:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/csl/arm-2010q1/bin:$PATH

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-uclinuxeabi-

export ARCH=arm
```